# vim: set fix jump marker in a source comment of the current file

Tags: vim

I'm a heavy **VIM** user but I missing one thing…

> setting a fix jump marker in a `comment` on different parts of a (large) current open file

What I expect:

1. setting a marker in a comment like: `// vim: marker(x)`
2. jumping to the marker with: `'x`

example (using tcl code) using `'x` to jump to function `p_structDEF_MqC`

```
proc p_func_arg_name_DEF_MqC {key value} {                                                                         
  set cmd "N"
  regexp {^(\w)#(.*)} $value dummy cmd value                                                                       
  set ::ARG_DEFAULT(k,$key) $cmd                                                                                   
  set ::ARG_DEFAULT(v,$key) $value                                                                                 
}

proc p_arg_name_DEF_MqC {key value} {
  func_arg_name_DEF_${::LANG}_MqC $key $value                                                                      
}           

## vim: marker(x)        
proc p_structDEF_MqC {name} {                                                                                      
  global xCLASS xPREFIX
  set prefix  [string range $name 0 end-1]                                                                         
  if {$prefix ne "Mq"} {
    lappend xPREFIX   "$prefix"                                                                                    
  }       
  lappend xCLASS    "${prefix}C"                                                                                   
}             

proc p_enumDEF_MqC {name argv} {                                                                                   
}               

proc p_typeDEF_MqC {VAR VALUE} {                                                                                   
}               

proc p_fupuDEF_MqC {name ret argv} {
}
```

Comment: what do you exactly want? like create a marker on the current buffer line: 2340, col: 2342?

Comment: I know that I can set *marker* with `m…` on the fly… bit I want set *local* marker **fix** in comments on the source-code. I want to open a file… and after open I want to have a *fix* set on marker **only** relevant for the **current** file… just to navigate to important parts of the file.

Comment: So what you meant "command" is  shell command instead of vim command?

Comment: sorry @kent … I mean **comment** … I wont to set a persistent marker in a *comment* which can *not* be replaced by *other* marker setup "on-the-fly" using `m…` syntax.

Comment: It looks like you want "tags" like `## TODO: foo bar baz` or `## FIXME: bar foo baz`. Use `:g/TODO` to list them and jump to the right one.

Comment: @romainl I don't understand what OP wanted...

Comment: @romaninl → this look like a normal search… "string" → ok… this always works → but I looking for persistant file`marks` http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create  an autocommand that scans files  for those marks,
and  create them  using  `setpos()`.  You can  go  as complex  as
you  want  in your  scripting,  i.e.  to  analyze the  next  line
and  determine  where  the  mark  should be.  Here  is  a  simple
implementation  in a  single command  that creates  marks on  the
first character of the next line:

```
au BufRead * g/vim: marker([a-z])/call setpos(
                      \ "'".matchstr(getline('.'), '(\zs\w'),
                      \ [0, getpos('.')[1]+1, 1, 0] )
```

---

This answer  is based mainly  on `:autocmd` and `:g`.  You should
check  the  help files  for  both  (`:h  :au`  and `:h  :g`).  An
autocommand  runs  the specified  command  when  a certain  event
happens  for files  matching a  specific pattern.  So, more  help
topics for you to read:

- `autocmd-events`
- `autocmd-patterns`

You can use the pattern to restrict this to certain files.

Then, we have the `:g`  command which searches for lines matching
a pattern and executes a command.  The search is where you modify
which flags are you looking for. Based on your comment, let's say
for example you  want to make the space after  `:` optional. Then
update your regex to:

```
vim: *marker([a-z])
```

Modify this as you need.

The command is centered in  the `setpos()` (again search the help
for it... everything I'm saying is  in the help anyway). It takes
two arguments, one  is what to set  and the other is  what to set
to. We want  to set a mark,  so we need to give  it an expression
like `"'a"`  to set mark `a`.  To figure out which  letter is the
mark supposed to be applied to, we use:

```
matchstr(getline('.', '(\zs\w')
```

Here we search  for the first letter after  the first parenthesis
(with `(\zs\w`) on  the text of our current  line, retrieved with
`getline()`. Search for the help  of all these functions. This is
concatenated to a quote, with `"'"  . {expr}` to make a `"'x"` if
the letter was `x`.

Then for the second argument, if must be an array similar to what
`getpos()`  returns.  Search  the  help  again.  However  we  are
modifying it,  to set  the mark  on the  *beginning of  the next*
line.  Thus we  only use  the line  item returned  by `getpos()`,
which is the second item, and add 1 to it.

```
[{buffer}, {line}, {col}, {virtual-offset}]
[0, getpos('.')[1]+1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: aha… I can not really read the vim scripting… but… scanning through a file and set a marker is basically a good It - some open question:
  1. restrict this to special file type…
  2. what is the "marker text" I shoul use… example in s shell-script it would be good to have something like `#vim:marker(x)` as jump target for `'x`

Comment: first try → 
    "MqC.c" 2130L, 66210C 
    Pattern not found: vim: marker([a-z])
    Betätigen Sie die EINGABETASTE oder geben Sie einen Befehl ein

Comment: I need some `backslash` to get it working… `au BufRead *.c g/vim: \*Marker(\[a-z])/call setpos…`

Comment: if a **Marker** is set on the file… this is **ok** bit without marker the `g` return an error: `Pattern not found: vim: \*Marker(\[a-z])`

Comment: @AndreasOtto I'm happy that you figured out the `silent` part, and sorry for not including it at first. About the escaping in the regex… it should not be necessary, unless you have `magic` turned off (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

the working solution based on previous answer:

```
au BufRead *.c silent! g/vim: \*Marker(\[a-z])/call setpos(
  \ "'".matchstr(getline('.'), '(\zs\w'),
  \ [0, getpos('.')[1]+1, 1, 0] )
```

→ thanks to @sidyll for the help.